# Why does 4.9E-324/2.0 returns 0.0 in java

Tags: java

I am writing a java program. When I do 4.9E-324/2, it returns 0.0. Using BigDecimal returns the correct value. Am I missing something?

```
double x = 4.9E-324/2.0; 
System.out.println(x); //result is zero
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.9E-324).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.0)).toPlainString()); //result is a non-zero value
```

Comment: It looks like you've discovered the whole reason that `BigDecimal` exists; to wit, `double` does not have arbitrary precision.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the choice of duplicate question.  That question covers the common question of why doubles can't represent numbers like `5.6` exactly, but it says nothing about the minimum positive value for a `double`, which is what this question is about.  I'll reopen this unless someone else can explain why this is an appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The defintion of [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) gives the answer.  This is the smallest positive value that a `double` can hold, equal to 2<sup>-1074</sup>, which is about 4.94 * 10<sup>-324</sup>.  If you put `4.9E-324` in your program, it's close enough to `MIN_VALUE` that the compiler will round up and use this value.  But then when you divide by 2, the result is too small for a `double`, so it is rounded down to 0.

The reason 2<sup>-1074</sup> is the smallest value has to do with the format of 64-bit floating-point numbers specified by [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).  This is a standard format, and most processors have built-in hardware to perform calculations on numbers in that format.  (By contrast, `BigDecimal` is represented as a Java array of unlimited length, so it's able to handle numbers with much greater precision; however, arithmetic on these numbers is done in software, making it much slower than calculations on `double`s.)  A 64-bit `double` consists of a sign bit, an 11-bit exponent field, and a 52-bit mantissa.  For a "normal" value, the exponent field is in the range 1 to 2046, and the actual exponent (power of 2) is offset from this so that the exponent ranges from -1022 to 1023.  The mantissa is 1.xxxxx...xxx (in binary), where the x's are the 52 bits of the mantissa.  The value represented by this format is 1.xxxxx...xxx * 2<sup>exponent</sup>.  So the smallest *normal* value is 1 * 2<sup>-1022</sup>, or [`Double.MIN_NORMAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_NORMAL).  If the exponent field is 0, and the mantissa bits are not all zero, then the floating-point value is a "denormal" number whose value is 2<sup>-1022</sup> * 0.xxxxx...xxx, where the x's are the 52-bit mantissa field.  (Denormal numbers can get smaller than normal ones, but they don't have 52 bits of precision like normal doubles do.)  The smallest possible value is thus 2<sup>-1022</sup> * 0.00000...001; the last part of this expression is 2<sup>-52</sup> since the mantissa field is 52 bits long, so that makes the smallest value 2<sup>-(1022+52)</sup> = 2<sup>-1074</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `4.9E-324` is less than the `4.94065645841246544e-324d` limit that a double has for decimal values.

A `BigDecimal` can hold many more digits, so it works there.